# VisualSVN: trying to download android code using VisualSVN on windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7, download, visualsvn

i want to download skia latest code which is used in android. Therefore i installed **VisualSVN** server on windows 7. but i'm not able to see anything in repository, its empty.

Settings are as follows:

**Repository root** : E:\Repositories.

**Server name**: skia.googlecode.com.

**port**: 443

**Server binding**: all IP addresses.

**Authentication**: use Windows authentication.

**Logging**: enabled access logging & operational logging.

Please let me know if i have done anything wrong.
Your inputs are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There are two components of an SVN system: The client and the server. The client is used to read the source code from the server. Your problem is that you are using a subversion server product to serve source code rather than using a client to pull it. I would recommend using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) as your client to download the source. This will allow you to right click on a windows directory and then "checkout" the contents of the repository locally.